PieCloudDB case sensitivity for table names
While using the PieCloudDB to create a database Test_Data, an error occurred when using \c Test_Data :
"FATAL: database "Test_Data" does not exist."

Upon checking with the \l, I noticed the database was listed as "test_data".
Does this mean that PieCloudDB uses lowercase by default? So if I want to use uppercase, how can I achieve it?

PieCloudDB automatically converts uppercase letters to lowercase. For example, if you execute the following command:
CREATE DATABASE Test_Data;

It will store the database name as test_data.
Therefore, you need to use the correct lowercase name(instead of Test_Data) :
\c test_data;

If you want to use uppercase, you need to use double quotes when creating the database:
CREATE DATABASE "Test_Data";

In this case, you also need to use double quotes:
\c "Test_Data"

